# Spring ModelAndView.setViewName("view") Search in Wrong Location

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am facing an strange issue right now. In my GET method, I am specifying the viewName. But Spring go and search for it in a different location.

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/Admin")
public class AdminTaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskDao taskDao;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    CSVValidation csvValidation;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Task/ViewAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getAllTasks() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("viewAllTasks");
        List<Task> tasks = (List<Task>) taskDao.findAll();
        modelAndView.addObject("tasks", tasks);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

But according to the debug:

```
    o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:327 - Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
    o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:402 - Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'Admin/Task/ViewAll'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/Admin/Task/ViewAll.jsp]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
    o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet:1218 - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'Admin/Task/ViewAll'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/Admin/Task/ViewAll.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    o.s.w.s.v.JstlView:377 - Added model object 'modelAndView' of type [org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView] to request in view with name 'Admin/Task/ViewAll'
    o.s.w.s.v.JstlView:377 - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.modelAndView' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'Admin/Task/ViewAll'
o.s.w.s.v.JstlView:207 - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/Admin/Task/ViewAll.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'Admin/Task/ViewAll'
```

But `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` go ans search for the a `/WEB-INF/jsp/Admin/Task/` folder to find a `ViewAll.jsp`. It does not contain such.

This `viewAllTasks.jsp` is contained inside the `/WEB-INF/jsp/` folder. Because if this it does not create the proper view and gives a 404:

```
 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/Admin/Task/ViewAll.jsp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem with the name spaces(imports). I was using

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

instead of

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

That was so unfortunate :(